# fetching data based on a condition in eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi I am working on a social networking site in **laravel**,
MY DATABASE is like...

```php
ID | FROM_ID | TO_ID | STATUS
1  |   1     |   2   | Accepted
1  |   2     |   1   | Sent
```

I want a query where status is (*seleted*) and `from_id` or `to_id` is `Auth::id()`
also with eager loding.
If `Auth::id` is in `from_id` (then details of the *user id* in `to_id`) and if `Auth::id` is in `to_id` (then details of the user id in `from_id`)

Comment: $user = Inbox::with('user')
                        ->where('status','Accepted')                    
                        ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('from_id', Auth::id())
                                ->orWhere('to_id', Auth::id());
                        })                      
                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')                   
                    ->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query :

I am providing query you can convert this in laravel :

SELECT inbox.*,user1.*,user2.* FROM inbox LEFT JOIN users as user1 on user1.id=inbox.FROM_ID LEFT JOIN users as user2 on user2.id=inbox.TO_ID WHERE STATUS ='Accepted' and (FROM_ID = Auth::id() OR TO_ID=Auth::id())

Comment: i Got this error   (2/2) QueryException

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join users as user2 on user2.id=inbox.to_id WHERE status ='Accepted' and (f' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT * FROM inbox LEFT JOIN users as user1 on user1.id=inbox.from_id, left join users as user2 on user2.id=inbox.to_id WHERE status ='Accepted' and (from_id = '1' OR TO_ID='1'))

Comment: Use this one : 
SELECT inbox.*,user1.*,user2.* FROM inbox LEFT JOIN users as user1 on user1.id=inbox.FROM_ID LEFT JOIN users as user2 on user2.id=inbox.TO_ID WHERE STATUS ='Accepted' and (FROM_ID = Auth::id() OR TO_ID=Auth::id())

Comment: here in palce of user1.* or user2.* try with giving the proper field name like user1.name as user1_name, user2.name as user2_name

Comment: thnx it worked as raw query, now how to convert this in eloquent? :)

Comment: Please try with :
$data = DB::table('inbox')->select('inbox.*','u1.name as u1_name','u2.name as u2_name')   
    ->leftJoin('users as u1', 'inbox.FROM_ID', '=', 'u1.id') 
    ->leftJoin('users as u2', 'inbox.TO_ID', '=', 'u2.id') 
    ->get();

Comment: anybody ? want help